# Android EditText : getting entered text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to get the after entered text.I  have done using `TextWatcher`.

There are some issues:

For example I want to enter 32.5. In that method I want to add to  `SET<Product>`.

Here each & every number its saving object.That means after enter 3 its add Product object into SET, then add 2 then also adding...

I want to avoid. Once I finish enter `EditText`,Then want to take it:

```
final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
txtQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
   Log.v("TAG", "afterTextChanged" + s.toString());
   String enterdPrice = txtPrice.getText().toString();
   double remainQty =0.00;
   Product enterdProduct = new Product();
   try{
      String enteredQty = s.toString();
      enterdProduct.setProductCode(txtCode.getText().toString());
      enterdProduct.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(enterdPrice));
      //enterdProduct.setQty(Double.parseDouble(enteredQty));
      // TO-DO  
      if (productSet.contains(enterdProduct)) {
          productSet.remove(enterdProduct);
      }
      productSet.add(enterdProduct);

      System.out.println("SIZE --" + productSet.size());
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Please give me idea, How we can get the EditText once enter I enetred text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get entered text on pressing "Enter" button on keyboard.

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Code from [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText)

Comment: Not always is ENTER being pressed. You may switch focus to another field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a separate button to add an object using the value in EditText?

Comment: No.I have list of product.If the quantity is entered by user, then need to add separate list & pass it to another activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to add separate list"?

Comment: If user enter quantity for particular product then need to add in to Set<Product> & want to pass anoter activity.How we can identify whether enter full text or not?

Comment: Just by tapping a button next to EditText. Or follow the Sergey's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `EditText` class and override `onEndBatchEdit` to implement the saving functionality after it has been edited in a 'batch' (could implement some sort of listener interface).